# Getting values from an array php

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array:

```
result script loadedArray
(
    [2015-06] => Array
    (
        [nb_uniq_visitors] => 12
        [nb_users] => 0
        [nb_visits] => 12
        [nb_actions] => 51
        [nb_visits_converted] => 0
        [bounce_count] => 4
        [sum_visit_length] => 1574
        [max_actions] => 22
        [bounce_rate] => 33%
        [nb_actions_per_visit] => 4.3
        [avg_time_on_site] => 131
    )

)
```

And I want to be able to access it as an object How can I do that?  I have

```
$object = new stdClass();

foreach ($arrayme as $key => $value) {
    $object->$key = $value;
}
```

But can't do `$object->2015-06->nb_visits`  to access the array object.

Comment: Does $object->2015-06['nb_visits'] work? seems you need to parse the array recoursively...

Comment: hi this doesn't work just throws an error:         PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '2015' (T_LNUMBER), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to cast the array into an object.

```
$arr = (object) array_map(function ($e) {
    return (object) $e;
}, $arr);
```

Then you can access like `$arr->{'2015-06'}->nb_uniq_visitors`.

Example: http://3v4l.org/FF2RT

Comment: Hi I got it wrong this doesn't quite work!  You need to do this to access the object  echo "array is ".$object->{'2015-06'}['bounce_rate'];  you don't need this casting stuff

Comment: Can you give me an example of the array and how would you access it?